# A determinant always $\ge 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I prove that this determinant is always bigger (or equal) than $0$? I've done this using the hard working method of determinant calculation, but I'm curious how can be done using the determinant properties. 
\begin{vmatrix}
 a_{1}^{2}+a_{2}^{2}+a_{3}^{2} &  a_{1}b_{1}+a_{2}b_{2}+a_{3}b_{3} \\ 
 a_{1}b_{1}+a_{2}b_{2}+a_{3}b_{3} & b_{1}^{2}+b_{2}^{2}+b_{3}^{2} 
\end{vmatrix} 
Is known that all of them are real numbers.

Answer (score 5):

I guess that the simples way to do this is by noticing that
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
 a_{1}^{2}+a_{2}^{2}+a_{3}^{2} &  a_{1}b_{1}+a_{2}b_{2}+a_{3}b_{3} \\ 
 a_{1}b_{1}+a_{2}b_{2}+a_{3}b_{3} & b_{1}^{2}+b_{2}^{2}+b_{3}^{2} 
\end{pmatrix} 
= \begin{pmatrix}
|a|^2 & a \cdot b\\
a\cdot b & |b|^2
\end{pmatrix}, $$
where $a = (a_1,a_2,a_3)$ and $b = (b_1,b_2,b_3)$, and then
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
|a|^2 & a \cdot b\\
a\cdot b & |b|^2
\end{vmatrix}
= |a|^2|b|^2-(a\cdot b)^2 \geq 0
$$
follows immediately from the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that your matrix is equal to

$$\begin{bmatrix}
 a_{1}^{2}+a_{2}^{2}+a_{3}^{2} &  a_{1}b_{1}+a_{2}b_{2}+a_{3}b_{3} \\ 
 a_{1}b_{1}+a_{2}b_{2}+a_{3}b_{3} & b_{1}^{2}+b_{2}^{2}+b_{3}^{2} 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
 a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\ 
 b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
 a_1 & b_1  \\ 
 a_2 & b_2  \\
 a_3 & b_3
\end{bmatrix}$$

and matrices of the form $AA^T$ always have nonnegative determinant.

Answer (score 0):

The working method of determinant calculation is not so hard if you  use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality appied to $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ and $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$.

$|\langle (a_1,a_2,a_3);(b_1,b_2,b_3)\rangle |\leq \|(a_1,a_2,a_3)\|\|(b_1,b_2,b_3)\|$ which is equivalent to say that $|a_1b_1+a_2b_2+a_3b_3|^2\leq (a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2)(b_1^2+b_2^2+b_3^2)$.

Comment: That's a great idea.Thank you!